# Native component for RNCardView does not exist

Tags: react-native, cardview

I know there is already a lot of similar posts with this error, but none of them are solving my issue ..

I've been trying to setup [react-native-cardview](https://github.com/Kishanjvaghela/react-native-cardview) on my project, but I keep on receiving the following error :

```
Invariant Violation: Native component for "RNCardView" does not exist

This error is located at:
    in RCTText (at Text.js:548)
    in Text (at Button.js:137)
    in RCTView (at View.js:71)
    in View (at Button.js:136)
    in TouchableNativeFeedback (at Button.js:128)
    in Button (at FormLogin.js:45)
    in RNCardView (at FormLogin.js:21)
    in RCTView (at View.js:71)
    in View (at FormLogin.js:20)
    in FormLogin (at SceneView.js:17)
    in SceneView (at CardStack.js:374)
    in RCTView (at View.js:71)
    in View (at CardStack.js:373)
    in RCTView (at View.js:71)
    in View (at CardStack.js:372)
    in RCTView (at View.js:71)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:147)
    in AnimatedComponent (at Card.js:12)
    in Card (at PointerEventsContainer.js:39)
    in Container (at CardStack.js:414)
    in RCTView (at View.js:71)
    in View (at CardStack.js:348)
    in RCTView (at View.js:71)
    in View (at CardStack.js:347)
    in CardStack (at CardStackTransitioner.js:66)
    in RCTView (at View.js:71)
    in View (at Transitioner.js:142)
    in Transitioner (at CardStackTransitioner.js:19)
    in CardStackTransitioner (at StackNavigator.js:38)
    in Unknown (at createNavigator.js:13)
    in Navigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:214)
    in NavigationContainer (at registerRootComponent.js:35)
    in RootErrorBoundary (at registerRootComponent.js:34)
    in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:35)
    in RCTView (at View.js:71)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
    in RCTView (at View.js:71)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:122)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
```

Here is my app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "sdkVersion": "25.0.0",
    "android": {
      "package": "hiking"
    },
    "name": "Hiking",
    "slug": "hiking",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "isDetached": true,
    "detach": {
      "scheme": "exp56fa0b6664574a6ea12b193494508d48",
      "androidExpoViewUrl": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/exp-exponent-view-code/android-v2.3.0-sdk25.0.0-0c32461b-a7c6-4ddc-b85b-32a80c4f18d9.tar.gz"
    }
  }
}
```

and package.json

```
{
  "name": "Hiking",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest-expo": "25.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.2.0"
  },
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^25.0.0",
    "react": "16.2.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-25.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-cardview": "^1.1.5",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.20.1",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.3",
    "rn-textinputlayout": "^1.0.5"
  }
}
```

react-native link react-native-cardview didn't solve the issue. 
Installing manually (as in the [readme](https://github.com/Kishanjvaghela/react-native-cardview#android)) didn't solve the issue.
Rebuilding and restarting the server didn't solve the issue.

I've been able to successfully install other libraries (such as [maps](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md) or textinputlayout).

Comment: I use this module succesfully. It has some auto linking issues (when running `react-native link`. Let me check and get back to you.

Comment: I've been trying to setup react-native-cardview on my project, but I keep on receiving the same error as the author had. My project made with react-native init, no Expo at all, I have checked all the files in an android folder about ten times and everything on its places as it should be as it described on a GitHub. I have no idea why it does not work.

Comment: I am also getting same issue , did you able to resolved the issue ?

Comment: I fixed my problem, the answer is accepted below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are running into the same issue, I managed to fix it by completely changing the way the project was handled.

What I had was a project made with `create-react-native-app`, which I ejected, to run it with Expo XDE.

I created another project with `react-native init`, copy-pasted my .js files and `npm install`, everything ran flawlessly.

It seems that Expo XDE didn't handle `react-native link` instructions properly, and was a bit lost.

Anyways, go for `react-native init` instead of ejecting a project.

Answer (score 1):

Just an add on @Noitidart Answer, your getPackages() inside "MainApplication.java" will look like this

```
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
        new MainReactPackage(),
        new RNCardViewPackage()
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this module succesfully. It has some auto linking issues (when running `react-native link`. This is the stuff I had to do to fix it for Android:

1. `android/app/src/main/java/com/YOUR_APP_ID_HERE/MainApplication.java`, remove `import com.reactlibrary.RNCardViewPackage;` and replace it with `import com.kishanjvaghela.cardview.RNCardViewPackage;`
2. The first fix should be all you need, but in same file make sure you have in `protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {` an entry `new RNCardViewPackage()`
3. In `android/settings.gradle` make sure you have these lines:

   include ':react-native-cardview'
     project(':react-native-cardview').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-cardview/android')

Lastly I dont think this is a problem with this module, but check to be sure. If you are using RN 0.47 plus, go to the node_modules directory and remove the `createJSModules` if its there - https://github.com/jsierles/react-native-audio/pull/216/files

Comment: Thanks ! I'm checking this and I'll be back to you if I have anything

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the solutions worked .. I think it's something with my particular setup, instead of a general problem. Thanks anyway !

Comment: @Arthur that's weird I use this succesfully across a bunch of projects since RN 0.46. Most recently installed it into 0.51. Try updating to latest RN.

Comment: I just ran react-native-git-upgrade, and it didn't fix anything. Which library are you using for cardview ? I use Kishanjvaghela/react-native-cardview

Comment: @ArthurAttout I use the same exact one, I even made some PRs to fix some stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds lika a webview version proble. You have to uninstall your current webview version and install the 5.8.1 version.

Execute the following steps:

1. react-native uninstall react-native-webview
2. react-native install react-native-webview@5.8.1

More information on https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/580